# iOS folder is showing empty on flutter repository while I pushed the project on GitHub

Tags: flutter

iOS folder is showing empty in repository while I pushed the flutter project on `GitHub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can make it with the terminal.

Go to terminal,

1 - `git add .` /// Important

2 - `git commit -m "Commit message"`

3 - `git push ...`

Answer (score 0):

You might have never added ios folder to git thats why code is not pushed.

Right-click on iOS folder and got to git-> add

Commit your code and now again push your code.

You will find all your code.